# Testing five samples from a lot with replacement for k defective items

Tags: probability

A lot of $50$ items has $40$ good items and $10$ bad items

Suppose we test five samples from the lot, with replacement.  let $X$ be the number of defective items in the sample.  Find $P[X = k]$

I know the number of ways to select five items is $50^k$.  What I'm confused about is what is the number of ways to select k defective items?

Is it $10^k * 50^{5-k}$ or $10^k * 50^{5-k} * C^5_k$ ?

Comment: The second one, since you don't care about the order.

Answer (score 1):

> I know the number of ways to select five items is $50^k$.

When it is selecting *with* replacement, yes.   $50^5$ ways in total.

> What I'm confused about is what is the number of ways to select k defective items?

You need to count ways to select $k$ from $10$ bad and $5-k$ from $40$ good, in some order.  Then $^{5}\mathrm C_k 10^k 40^{5-k}$